# What do the * mean in the output of DNU List?

Tags: .net, dnu

When I run [DNU](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility) List I see the following output:

[image]

What do the asterisks (highlighted in pink) mean?

The version of DNU I'm using is:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility  
Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231  
Type:         Clr  
Architecture: x86  
OS Name:      Windows  
OS Version:   10.0  
Runtime Id:   win10-x86
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out:

[* means direct dependency.](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/)

Which I think means that the dependency is listed in the project.json directly.